# Adding content to a linear layout dynamically?

Tags: android, android-layout

If for example I have defined a root linear layout whose orientation is vertical:

**main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/my_root"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"

    <!-- I would like to add content here dynamically.-->

</LinearLayout>
```

Inside the root linear layout, I would like to add multiple *child linear layouts*, each of the child linear layout orientation is *horizontal*. With all these I could end up with a table like output.

For example root with *child* layout such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/my_root"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"

    <!-- 1st child (1st row)-->
    <LinearLayout 
        ...
       android:orientation="horizontal">

          <TextView .../>
          <TextView .../>
          <TextView .../>
    </LinearLayout>

     <!-- 2nd child (2nd row)-->
     ...
</LinearLayout>
```

Since the number of child linear layouts and their contents are quite dynamic, I've decide to add content to the root linear layout programmatically.

How can the second layout be added to the first programmatically, which could also set all the layout attributes for each child and add more other elements inside child?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

In your `onCreate()`, write the following

```
LinearLayout myRoot = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_root);
LinearLayout a = new LinearLayout(this);
a.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
a.addView(view1);
a.addView(view2);
a.addView(view3);
myRoot.addView(a);
```

`view1`, `view2` and `view3` are your `TextView`s. They're easily created programmatically.

Comment: Anyone know why this is?  Why can't I just do this.addView(view1) if this extends LinearLayout?

Comment: Nice, but when should I use this, and when should I use TableLayout instead? Is it just a matter of personal taste?

Comment: we must add linear layout into dynamic horizontalScrollView too. tnx : )

Answer (score 79):

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.child, null);
layout.addView(child);
```

Comment: If we do like this. How do we manage to handle click events inside "layout.child"?

Comment: @Warapitiy Use `child.findViewById` to get the element and set onclick listener.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve LinearLayout cascading like this:

```
LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_root);    
LinearLayout llay1 = new LinearLayout(this);    
root.addView(llay1);
LinearLayout llay2 = new LinearLayout(this);    
llay1.addView(llay2);
```

Answer (score 2):

I found more accurate way to adding views like linear layouts in kotlin (Pass parent layout in inflate() and false)

```
val parentLayout = view.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.llRecipientParent)
val childView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_recipient, parentLayout, false)
parentLayout.addView(childView)
```