# ListView inside listView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am trying to implement a listView inside another listView as shown in [android: listview in listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652814/android-listview-in-listview)

The problem is that only the first item of the child list is visible while remaining remain hidden.

Comment: FYI, this setup will not work well.

Comment: list view inside list view is not better idea but you can use alternate ideas if its not affect your layouts. check this : http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2013/01/android-better-alternative-of.html

Answer (score 0):

What is the usage for you to give Listview inside Listview..Better you can use expandable ListView

Answer (score 0):

First, why do you want to put a ListView in a ListView ? Maybe your problem can be solved by using an [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html).

A ListView is a scrollable component and it's not a good idea to nest scrollable components.

If you still want to use nested ListView, you have to know that the calculated height of a ListView is the height of his first element.

So if you want to use a ListView in a ListView, you will have to code a CustomListView and Override some methods as :

- onLayout
- onMeasure
- onDraw / dispatchDraw

To know more about Custom components, here is a nice explanation given by Chiuki Chan : [Follow the link](http://www.sqisland.com/talks/android-custom-components/#25)

Answer (score 0):

I just thought you may had something wrong in item XML file.Check whether you used "match_parent" or "fill_parent".

Answer (score 0):

We can use ExpandableHeightGridView and set expanded true.