# How to work, when listview inside the scrollview?

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, scroll, scrollview

I doing this In **Android 1.6 and 2.2** ...

I have One ***ScrollView*** in the Activity (All the content in the ScrollView) ...

And Second is, One ***ListView*** in the Activity ....

When I Scroll ListView, at that time ScrollView is scrolling but ***ListView's Scroll is not working*** ...

I provide the **scatch** of the **problem** which I have ...

If anyone have solution of this, then please share ...

[image]

Comment: Romain Guy (Android engineer) [suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3496042/1521536) that you should ***not*** use a scrollable view inside a `ScrollView`. This question seems to be a duplicate of that answer's question too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I put a ListView into a ScrollView without it collapsing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

here  parentScroll = your main scrollview
and childScroll = your listview

```
parentScroll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    Log.v("PARENT", "PARENT TOUCH");
                    findViewById(R.id.child_scroll).getParent()
                            .requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    return false;
                }
            });

  childScroll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    Log.v("CHILD", "CHILD TOUCH");
                    // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of
                    // child view
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Comment: @kyogs I liked your answer and its working also. I have a recycler view and first item of that recyclerView is a nestedScrollView containing a textview. Now using your code i am able to scroll both textview and recyclerView but the textview gets scrolled only when scrolled from area inside  nestedScrollView which is blank. What to do if I want scrolling event if i scroll touching the text field

Comment: But it stoped the childScroll to scroll

Comment: its not working.
when i debug its not executing onTouchListner