# android textview scrollview in layout scrollview

Tags: android

I set the `ScrollView` in my `LinearLayout`. I want a `TextView` to scroll. I tried to use `ScrollView` in xml like this. But, it's not working.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp"
    tools:context=".SubpagesLayout.ReportResult">

    <!-- first scrollView -->
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_corner_blue"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/personalInformation"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/birthDate" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=" TestData" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- second scrollView -->
            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textOphthalmoscopy"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:text="standard instrth various settings that allow focusing and adjustment of the light source to accommodate the viewer and to evaluate various features of the fundus." />
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>    
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried another way like this, but it's still not working too.

```
android:maxLines = "AN_INTEGER"
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

I used

```
myTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

So how to let `TextView` to scroll? If it is the second `ScrollView`.

Comment: you can not use nested scroll view , try using the NestedScrollView provided by android , however avoid nesting scrolls if u can

Comment: yes , it's NestedScrollView !  thanks your help , but why should i avoid NestedScrollView ?

Comment: i dont know the technical answer to this, but physically its not advisable to have one scroll inside another scrolling surface ,since android is based on MATERIAL UI

Comment: it's ok , you save me a lot , i see know , thanks for your help @Ak9637

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using a `NestedScrollView` along with a `ListView` for showing the scrollable `TextView`.

The `ListView` will have a fixed size so that it'll not take the total height of the items inside.

So the layout may look like this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp"
    tools:context=".SubpagesLayout.ReportResult">

    <!-- first scrollView -->
    <NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_corner_blue"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/personalInformation"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/birthDate" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=" TestData" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                <!--set a fixed height-->
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                .. Other attributes
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </NestedScrollView>    
</LinearLayout>
```

And the list item of the `ListView` may contain the `TextView` you want to scroll. Set the height of the `TextView` to `wrap_content`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp"
    tools:context=".SubpagesLayout.ReportResult">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textOphthalmoscopy"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="standard instrth various settings that allow focusing and adjustment of the light source to accommodate the viewer and to evaluate various features of the fundus." />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now your `ListView` will have a single item and this will scroll with the default behaviour of list.

The whole layout will be scrolled via `NestedScrollView`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: ha it's you again ! really thanks for your help . This way add a new layout , it's more complicated , i take it anyway , thanks @Reaz Murshed

Comment: Glad to find you here again. Please upvote if helpful. :)

Answer (score 1):

Having a scrollView inside another scrollView is not a good prictice but ant a you check below links it may fix you problem.

[Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824542/android-scrollview-inside-another-scrollview-doesnt-scroll)

[Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490821/scrollview-inside-scrollview/13634181#13634181)