# Scrollview having HorizontalScrollview lags when scrolling

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, layout, scrollview

I am trying to use horizontal scrollview inside a scroll view. My parent scroll isn't scrolling smoothly. Although my child scroll is scrolling smoothly, I want to achieve smooth scrolling of parent scroll. I have tried every method, I have in my mind setting HardwareAccelerated to false worked but it removed elevation from my views.

Main Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:background="#ECEFF1"

android:clipToPadding="false">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corners"
    android:clipToPadding="false"


    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:translationZ="5dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="42dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="121dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/enquiry"

        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/visa"
        android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/phone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:text="Enquiry"
        android:textColor="@color/navigationBarColor"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/visa"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/holidays"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/globe" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Visa"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/holidays"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/plane" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:text="Holidays"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark" />
 </RelativeLayout>

 <include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/app_bar" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:fontFamily="serif"
    android:text="Call"
    android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"


    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:text="Pilgrimage"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/pilg"
            class="com.example.admin.myapplication.Pilgrimage"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

            android:background="@drawable/round_corners"
            android:elevation="5dp">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:background="@drawable/hu" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="155dp"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:text="Hajj And Umrah"
                android:textColor="@color/navigationBarColor"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
                android:text="Ramzan Umrah"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="12sp"

                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="210dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
                android:text="29 Days/30 Nights"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="205dp"
                android:text="Starts From Rs.65,000/-"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:text="Holiday Packages"
            android:textColor="@color/navigationBarColor"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/child"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="none">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/international"
                    class="com.example.admin.myapplication.International"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="225dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

                    android:background="@mipmap/ll"
                    android:elevation="5dp"
                    android:padding="-25dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView11"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
                        android:fontFamily="serif"
                        android:text="International"
                        android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />
                </RelativeLayout>


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/dom1"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="225dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:background="@mipmap/rajasthan"
                    android:elevation="5dp">


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView12"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                        android:fontFamily="serif"
                        android:text="Domestic"
                        android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:text="Social"
            android:textColor="@color/navigationBarColor"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="335dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:fontFamily="serif"
    android:text="Al Shariq Enterprises"
    android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />


  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: in top of your layout please try using nestedScroll then I guess it should work fine! just_a_tip

Comment: for horizontal scroll people are oriented towards usage of RecyclerView single row gridView! that is way smoother! HorizontalScrollView its famous for its lacky behave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `NestedScrollView` like this :-

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"                
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp">

  <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:text="Pilgrimage"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/pilg"
            class="com.example.admin.myapplication.Pilgrimage"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

            android:background="@drawable/round_corners"
            android:elevation="5dp">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:background="@drawable/hu" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="155dp"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:text="Hajj And Umrah"
                android:textColor="@color/navigationBarColor"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
                android:text="Ramzan Umrah"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="12sp"

                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="210dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
                android:text="29 Days/30 Nights"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="205dp"
                android:text="Starts From Rs.65,000/-"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:text="Holiday Packages"
            android:textColor="@color/navigationBarColor"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/child"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="none">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/international"
                    class="com.example.admin.myapplication.International"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="225dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

                    android:background="@mipmap/ll"
                    android:elevation="5dp"
                    android:padding="-25dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView11"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
                        android:fontFamily="serif"
                        android:text="International"
                        android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />
                </RelativeLayout>


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/dom1"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="225dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:background="@mipmap/rajasthan"
                    android:elevation="5dp">


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView12"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                        android:fontFamily="serif"
                        android:text="Domestic"
                        android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:text="Social"
            android:textColor="@color/navigationBarColor"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="335dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
 </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

For basic details you can check [this link.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think that this happens because both of your `ScrollViews` reacts to scrolling so it seems to you that it lags, but it actually don't, its just vertical `ScrollView` interrupting horizontal `ScrollView`.

It is not recommended using `ScrollView` inside another `ScrollView`. Instead use `NestedScrollView` as in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36891138/9389798)

Comment: Problem persists.. it is still scrolling slowly