# Disable / Enable Scroll for ListView in android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scrollview

I have a `ListView` inside `ScrollView`. I can enable scroll of `ListView` by

```
listView.getParent().requestDisallowInterCeptTouchEvent(true);
```

But the problem is when i scroll up in listView and it reaches top it should scroll to parent view i.e. parent scroll has to work . How can i do this ? any suggestion please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15062365/how-to-work-when-listview-inside-the-scrollview try this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable scrolling of a ListView contained within a ScrollView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212890/disable-scrolling-of-a-listview-contained-within-a-scrollview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to embed your upper view i.e any viewgroup above list view into listview header. ListView has a method, listview.addHeaderView().  That way you would be able to scroll your list (Whole View) even on small size display and you don't need scrollview.

Answer (score 6):

```
listView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            return true; // Indicates that this has been handled by you and will not be forwarded further.
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

OR

To make the View unselectable just get the view and `.setClickable(false)`

OR

```
listView.setScrollContainer(false);
```

Comment: Will `return false` allow `listview` to scroll ?

Comment: Your response was very useful to me, I also used your method

Answer (score 4):

You can override ScrollView class and insert these methods inside:

```
private boolean isScrollEnabled = true;

public void enableScroll(boolean isScrollEnabled ) {
    this.isScrollEnabled = isScrollEnabled ;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (isScrollEnabled) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is the cleanest solution to achieve this. You only call `scrollView.enableScroll(true)` to enable scrolling or `scrollView.enableScroll(false)` to disable it.