# Scrollable TextView inside ScrollView

Tags: android, textview, scrollview, ontouchlistener

I just implemented "Pull to Refresh" to my code today and had a little problem. While scrolling the lyrics up, the pull to refresh (PTR) action occurs. I would like to disable that while the user touches on the `lyricsTextView`, or rather the whole space around that `TextView`. I have the title shown above the `lyricsTextView` which will not be scrollable.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainScrollView">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/playerFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:tag="playerFragment">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="title"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/artistTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/titleTextView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="artist"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/albumImageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/artistTextView"
                android:alpha="76"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/artistTextView"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

            android:id="@+id/lyricsScrollView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dip">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lyricsTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:maxLines="999999"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:text="lyrics/>
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

I tried using this code which I found on StackOverFlow but wasn't able to accomplish what I want.

```
playerFragment.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
        return false;
    }
});

lyricsScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of
        // child view
        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return false;
    }
});
```

screenshot:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/36670712/Screenshot_2015-02-15-00-40-26%5B1%5D.png

Comment: Can you please link to the stack overflow question where you found this code?

Comment: @CurlyCorvus here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15062365/how-to-work-when-listview-inside-the-scrollview

Comment: see the following link for the answer:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605486/edittext-not-scrollable-inside-scrollview/41134777#41134777](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605486/edittext-not-scrollable-inside-scrollview/41134777#41134777)

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the scrollable textview `scrolltext` and the parent scrollview `scrollview`.

The first problem that i can see in your code is that in the parent's OnTouchListener, you are referencing the parent of `v`, and in that context `v` is the parent itself. In the answer you are relying on, you need to get the parent view on `scrolltext`, not the parent of the parent itself.

Second, the views you are setting the OnTouchListeners on are wrong. You need to set on on the `scrollview` and one on the `textview`. In the code you posted you set one on a fragment containing the entire layout and one on the `scrollview`. (I assume these are the fragment and scroll view based on their names.)

Comment: If I add a parent scrollview, the whole parent will be scrollable, take a look at the post I have edited.

Comment: @BrandonOng The lyricsTextView text view already has a parent scrollview, but i see now that the layout has two scrollviews. Which one of these scroll views has PTR? If it's mainScrollView, then why do you need to have a scrollable textview inside it's own scrollview?

Comment: I dont get what you mean... do you understand the pic i posted?