# ListView in scroll Activity

Tags: android, android-listview

i need to have 2 list  views in one activity, but it will be looked next:
after scroling all elements from listView - i will see listView two.
 i read [android: listview in listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652814/android-listview-in-listview)
Some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

Please take a look at [this](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-expandable-list-view-example/) tutorial. I used this when I tried to learn how to use the ExpandableListView.

Comment: Please update if it worked/did not work so that I can find another solution. Glad to be able to help :)