# Scrollable Custom Listview inside Gridview in android

Tags: android

I have a GridView that displays items, each item is a ListView.
The problem is that I can't scroll the ListView items, seems like the GridView is obtaining the focus or preventing it from the ListView

*** activity_layout.xml ***

```
<GridView
            android:id="@+id/listMonthly"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:divider="@drawable/above_shadow"
            android:numColumns="7"
            android:clipToPadding="true"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:dividerHeight="10dp"
            android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
            android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="10dp" android:stretchMode="columnWidth">

</GridView>
```

*** custom_calendar.xml ***

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:overScrollMode="always"
        android:id="@+id/customList"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/txtdt"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The View is ... [calendar View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yYPS.png)

as figure shows .. i have a listview on every gridview item.
how to make this listview scrollable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution from here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/33185470/6334037

I made some changes in it and it works perfectly.

```
<com.exapmle.util.NestedListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:overScrollMode="always"/>
```

*** NestedListView.java ***

```
public class NestedListView extends ListView implements View.OnTouchListener, AbsListView.OnScrollListener {
    private int listViewTouchActionDown;
    private static final int MINIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE = 1;

    public NestedListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        listViewTouchActionDown = 0;
        setOnScrollListener(this);
        setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (getAdapter() != null && getAdapter().getCount() > MINIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE) {
            if (listViewTouchActionDown == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                scrollBy(0, -1);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (getAdapter() != null && getAdapter().getCount() > MINIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                scrollBy(0, 1);
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                scrollBy(0, -1);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int newHeight = 0;
        final int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        if (heightMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            ListAdapter listAdapter = getAdapter();
            if (listAdapter != null && !listAdapter.isEmpty()) {
                int listPosition = 0;
                for (listPosition = 0; listPosition < listAdapter.getCount()
                        && listPosition < MINIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE; listPosition++) {
                    View listItem = listAdapter.getView(listPosition, null, this);
                    //now it will not throw a NPE if listItem is a ViewGroup instance
                    if (listItem instanceof ViewGroup) {
                        listItem.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    }
                    listItem.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
                    newHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
                }
                newHeight += getDividerHeight() * listPosition;
            }
            if ((heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) && (newHeight > heightSize)) {
                if (newHeight > heightSize) {
                    newHeight = heightSize;
                }
            }
        } else {
            newHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), newHeight);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to "force" the scrollView not to be scrollable, by overriding the `onTouch` on the scrollView and specifying that the view does not handle any event :

```
gridview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: See my edit, this way should exclude any event event from being processed by the gridView

Comment: nope. this answer also didn't work. Listview still not scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

It was discouraged to use scrollable inside another scrollable view in Android. But in the latest support library you can find [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html) which was added for such cases. You can use it instead of you `ListView` or `GridView`.
More info you can find in [this](http://ivankocijan.xyz/android-nestedscrollview/) tutorial.

Comment: thanks for the tutorials(really appreciated). but both scrollable views are in different different layout. then how can i use **NestedScrollView**.

Comment: You can put vertical LinearLayout into NestedSctollView and add all you items from list view via addView().

Comment: It doesn't matter that they are in different files. custom_calendar.xml layout will be attached to GridView as a separate view.

Comment: Ok got it. I'll try it.

Comment: Thank you. It's good but difficult to add view dynamically. I found an easy solution for it.