# How to set OnItemClickListener event for ListView in List item of Listview

Tags: android, listview

I want to add `onClick()` event for `listview`. Because i have `listview` inside `listview`. and i want when i click on parent listview item then open new activity, but when i click on child `listview` item , the code of parent `listview` item click is not working, How can I give `onClick()` event for child `ListView`.

```
 heightListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LocationMapHistory.this,LocationHistoryActivity.class));
            }
        });
```

this code only working if i hide child `listview` into parent `listview` item.

Comment: have you tried implementing your child listview click listener in your parent list's adapter ?. The problem here is that your parent listview takes focus/scroll/click listener whenever you click on your child list.

Comment: have you tried disabling parent click listener?

Comment: i want click listener for parent list item , not for child

Comment: @krishsingh try using interfaces then :)

Comment: I think we need to set mParentListView.setTouchInterceptEnabled(true);

Comment: wait @ jettimadhuChowdary let me check

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'setTouchInterceptEnabled(boolean)' 

for this "I think we need to set mParentListView.setTouchInterceptEnabled(true)"

Comment: Maybe this solution can be good for you: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/13415566/7135613](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13415566/7135613)

Comment: not working @Orhan Avan

Comment: "@krishsingh try using interfaces then :) – Umair" thanks via using interface it's working

Answer (score 0):

As per [ChrLipp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11653149/2006009), it is not recommended to create a `Listview` within a `ListView`. My workaround on this is to create a `ViewGroup` instead ie. `LinearLayout` and manually manage the `Viewgroup` children.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    MyHolder myholder = (MyHolder)holder;
    View child = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.child, myholder.viewgroup, false);
    child.setOnClickListener(yourListener);
    holder.viewgroup.addView(child);
}
```

Comment: app crash :

 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView


because its not recyclerview , its listview

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Rx Event Bus for this. Event Bus utils make it easy to recognize which event is being called. For example in your case inside adapter's item holder you can get the position of item in the list view which is clicked.

```
heightListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            RXEventBusUtils.getInstance().postEvent(new StartActivityEvent(i));
        }
    });
```

RxEventBusUtils class

```
public class RXEventBusUtils {

private static RXEventBusUtils sRXEventBusUtils;
private PublishSubject<Object> mPublishSubject;

public static RXEventBusUtils getInstance() {
    if (sRXEventBusUtils == null) {
        sRXEventBusUtils = new RXEventBusUtils();
    }
    return sRXEventBusUtils;
}

public PublishSubject getSubject() {
    if (null == mPublishSubject) {
        mPublishSubject = PublishSubject.create();
    }
    return mPublishSubject;
}

public void postEvent(Object event) {
    getSubject().onNext(event);
}
}
```

StartActivityEvent class

```
public class StartActivityEvent {
int position;

public StartActivityEvent () {

}

public int getPosition() {
    return position;
}
}
```

and inside your activity you have to subscribe the Rx Event Bus Utils inside onCreate method.

```
 disposable = RXEventBusUtils.getInstance().getSubject().subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(this::onReceiveEvent);
```

this line subscribe(register) the event bus and creates a method onReceiveEvent and passes event as object. Inside this method you can check which event is received here and so you can perform your desire function.

```
private void onReceiveEvent(Object event) {
    if (event instanceof StartActivityEvent) {
      //    start activity       
    }

    if (event instanceof DeleteItemEvent) {
       /// delete item etc 
    }


}
```

And do not forget to add dependency in app level gradle file

```
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.5'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
```

remember one thing you have to create separate event class for different kind of function.

so for child listview you have to simply register new event to perform click listener

```
childListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        RXEventBusUtils.getInstance().postEvent(new DeleteItemEvent(i));
    }
});
```

DeleteItemEvent Class

```
public class DeleteItemEvent {
int position;

public DeleteItemEvent () {

 }

public int getPosition() {
return position;
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**using interface** , 
**i found it**

> create a interface then implement in parent adapter and pass with
>   child adapter , while user will click child item then call the
>   interface , its will notify parent item , and perform your code .