# Adding LinearLayout inside a ListView dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I have created a fragment OrderFragment in which I have created two tabs, Order_Subscription and Order_OneTime, each of which is also a fragment. I used a listView inside the two fragments.

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listViewSubscription">
</ListView>
```

I want to populate the list view in the format of row_order.xml which contains Customer Details and Product they buy(LinearLayout, id= "product_details" below). The products can be variable in number so I want to dynamically add the linear Layout.

row_order.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/row_card"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/customer_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:text="Customer Name"
            android:textStyle="bold">

        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/address_phoneno"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:text="Phone Number"
            android:textStyle="bold">

        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/amount_left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:text="Amount Left"
            android:textStyle="bold">

        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="20sp"
        android:paddingRight="10sp"
        android:id="@+id/product_details">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Product Name">

        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quantity_order"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Qty">

        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/amount_order"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Amount">

        </TextView>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/delivered_checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

        </CheckBox>
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

In the Order_Subscription.java Fragment, my getView function is as follows.

```
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            //Following is for Customer Details. This works
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View row_order = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_order, parent, false);
            TextView cust_name = row_order.findViewById(R.id.customer_name);
            TextView ph_no_addr = row_order.findViewById(R.id.address_phoneno);
            TextView amnt = row_order.findViewById(R.id.amount_left);
            cust_name.setText(customerName[position]);
            ph_no_addr.setText(ph_no[position]);


            //Product details I want to add. Right now adding without loop
           LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)row_order.findViewById(R.id.product_details);
           linearLayout.removeAllViews();
           View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.id.product_details, null);
            TextView prod_name = linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
            prod_name.setText("New Product");
            TextView quat_order = linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.quantity_order);
            TextView amnt_order = linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.amount_order);
            quat_order.setText("50");
            amnt_order.setText("100");
            linearLayout.addView(child);




            return row_order;
        }
    }
```

I want to add product details dynamically. By default there's one set of LinearLayout(product_details) because of XML. RemoveAllViews() is able to clear it. And I can set text of that one layout if I don't use removeAllView function.

I already checked: [android: listview in listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652814/android-listview-in-listview)
I'm not able to figure out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Use `RecyclerView`

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun For just the inner LinearLayout or the whole thing? Sorry, I'm new to Android.

Answer (score 0):

Strongly suggest that you should use `ReceyclerView` if you don't want then at least use `ListAdapter` with `ListView` so it would handle wiew adding binding and removing for you.

Here is an [example](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)